# Find all values of a for which $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ form a basis for ${\bf R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Question is: Find all values of a for which $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$  form a basis for ${\bf R}^3$, where $v_1=(a^2,0,1)$, $v_2=(0,a,2)$, and $v_3=(1,0,1)$.

My thoughts:
I put it into a matrix to help visualize: 
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2 &0 &1\\
 0& a &0\\
 1 &2 &1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Well, I can see right away that if $a=\pm1$ then we have 2 equal vectors $\implies$ linearly dependent.
I also see that if $a=0$ we have a row of zeros $\implies$ Not spanning ${\bf R}^3$.
So, I know that a cannot equal $-1$, 0, or 1

My problems:
1. I'm not sure how to show that any other value will form a basis.
2. I don't know what how would I solve similar questions like this, where it's not as obvious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
a^2&0&1\\
0&a&2\\
1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
=a(a^2-1),
$$
hence only solutions are $0$, $1$, $-1$.