# For what values of $ a $ is the set $A=\{(a^2,0,1),(0,a,2),(1,0,1)\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, linear-transformations

For this I used the method of making the determinant nonzero. First I create the array

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & 0 & 1\\
0 & a & 2\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then $\det(A)=a^3-a=a(a^2-1)$

Where we can see that for the determinant to be different from zero $ a $ cannot take the values of
$0,1,-1$.

Therefore the values that $ a $ can take so that $ A $ is a base of $\mathbb{R} ^ 3 $ are $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0,1, -1\}$.

This is correct?

Comment: Correct.........

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank u!

Comment: It's easy to see that if $a\in\{1,-1\}$ then the first listed vector is the same as the third, and if $a=0$ then a vector with non-zero second component cannot be generated

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I had not noticed that observation. Thanks!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have a question. Could you help me? I have this problem: For values of $a$ the vector $(a ^ 2, a, 1)$ is in the $\langle (1,2,3), (1,1,1), (0,1,2) \rangle$. My question is, should I find scalars $ \alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma $ such that $\alpha (1,2,3) + \beta (1,1,1) + \gamma (0,1,2) = (a ^ 2, a, 1) $?

Comment: @Kale_1729:  if you have a different question, post a different question

Comment: I'm reluctant to accept the proposed target duplicate.  Although the Questions are nearly the same, the one Answer to the older Question (not this one) is short and not quite faithful in presenting a solution.  I'd be more comfortable in swapping which one to close because the first Answer here is the best of those given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Another approach would be to use Gaussian elimination. If $a = 0$, you immediately see that the first two rows are a multiple of each other. If $a \neq 0$, then multiplying the last row with $a^2$ and subtracting the first row gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & 0 & 1\\
0 & a & 2\\
0 & 0 & a^2-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This matrix is invertible if and only if  $a \neq -1,0,1$.

Comment: Very well. Thanks!

Comment: I have a question. Could you help me? I have this problem: For values of $a$ the vector $(a ^ 2, a, 1)$ is in the $\langle (1,2,3), (1,1,1), (0,1,2) \rangle$. My question is, should I find scalars $ \alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma $ such that $\alpha (1,2,3) + \beta (1,1,1) + \gamma (0,1,2) = (a ^ 2, a, 1) $?

Comment: @Kale_1729 Yes, but you should post a new question for that rather than using this one. Besides, if you are satisfied with the answers you got, you can upvote and accept them on the left hand side. This will remove it from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

That's a correct solution, for a more general case you may refer to [this similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014445/find-all-values-of-a-for-which-v-1-v-2-v-3-form-a-basis-for-bf-r3)

Comment: Very well. Thanks!